# Java - parse JSON payload, omit broken objects in array

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

Is it possible to omit broken objects when parsing JSON payload into POJO?

example payload:

```
[
     {
        "someField": "this_object_seems_to_be_ok"
     },
     { 
        "someBrokenStructure"= "equals_sign_instead_of_colon_here"
     }
]
```

I'd like to get the list with only one properly structured object. Is it achievable with any of the existing frameworks?

Comment: One option might be to use regex or something to strip out the broken json, or just replace the "key" = "value" with "key": "value",

Comment: @sw1 i think you should create your own parser of the particular json to remove incorrect (from structural point of view) pairs of key/value and then you will be able to parse it with Jackson.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was afraid of :)

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to write deserialiser for an invalid `JSON` payload with expected result in all cases. `JSON` payload with many nested `JSON Objects` and `JSON Arrays` can be broken on many ways. In your case it is quite simple structure and should be easy to maintain.

So, you need to implement custom `List` deserialiser which could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.MapType;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./src/main/resources/test.json");

        SimpleModule skipInvalidObjectsModule = new SimpleModule();
        skipInvalidObjectsModule.addDeserializer(List.class, new ListJsonDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(skipInvalidObjectsModule);

        List<Map<String, Object>> result = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, List.class);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

class ListJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<Object>> {

    @Override
    public List<Object> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        MapType mapType = ctxt.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, Object.class);
        JsonDeserializer<Object> mapDeserializer = ctxt.findRootValueDeserializer(mapType);

        List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

        p.nextToken();
        while (p.currentToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            if (p.currentToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                try {
                    result.add(mapDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt));
                } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            try {
                p.nextToken();
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Above code prints first errors:

```
Unexpected character ('=' (code 61)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 27]
Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 29]
Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 30]
Unexpected character ('q' (code 113)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 31]
Unexpected character ('u' (code 117)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 32]
Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 33]
Unexpected character ('l' (code 108)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 34]
Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 35]
Unexpected character ('_' (code 95)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 36]
Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 37]
Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 38]
Unexpected character ('g' (code 103)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 39]
Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 40]
Unexpected character ('_' (code 95)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 41]
Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 42]
Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 43]
Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 44]
Unexpected character ('t' (code 116)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 45]
Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 46]
Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 47]
Unexpected character ('d' (code 100)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 48]
Unexpected character ('_' (code 95)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 49]
Unexpected character ('o' (code 111)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 50]
Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 51]
Unexpected character ('_' (code 95)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 52]
Unexpected character ('c' (code 99)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 53]
Unexpected character ('o' (code 111)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 54]
Unexpected character ('l' (code 108)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 55]
Unexpected character ('o' (code 111)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 56]
Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 57]
Unexpected character ('_' (code 95)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 58]
Unexpected character ('h' (code 104)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 59]
Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 60]
Unexpected character ('r' (code 114)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 61]
Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 62]
Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 63]
```

And finally result:

```
[{someField=this_object_seems_to_be_ok}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Michal Ziober answer can be helpful in many cases, I found that I can try with Gson from Google. It has the lenient mechanism that tries to parse non-standard structures.
For more information see [this link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-builder-relax-gson-with-lenient)